# How to update the data in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

Trying to updating the solr document with below passed data

```
[{"id":"6","status":{"set":"3"}},
{"id":"10","status":{"set":"3"}}]
```

Throwing this error message :

```
"msg": "Expected: OBJECT_START but got ARRAY_START at [16]",
```

Please suggest a best way to update solr 4.0 document data with single url.

Comment: how are you adding them, using curl?

Comment: No in the admin itself.

Comment: Adding multiple document is not possible from solr admin UI. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from lucene discussion page: [Reference Link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Submitting-Multiple-JSON-documents-from-Solr-Admin-Documents-tt4093155.html#a4093175)

> The admin page accepts only a `single JSON document` to be added, because it wraps it in tags like so...
>
> > {"add":{ "doc": YOUR_TEXT_AREA_INPUT, ....

You can use the `curl utility` or `post.jar` for adding `multiple document` at the same time.

Reference for the updating solr document using curl . [Updating a Solr Index with JSON](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-JSONFormattedIndexUpdates)

Comment: Seems to be correct, but why does the form says "Document(s)" instead of "Document", then? This is misleading, at least, beacuse nobody expects that multiple documents won't work when plural is mentioned in the forms label.